# Get property value instead of just Id

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have this line i an Umbraco solution, which gets me the ids of the nodes selected, comma seperated.

But what i want to get, in a oneliner, is a value of the node(s) selected. 
So currently it is just returning the node id like "1001, 1000, 1003" or just "1003" if only one is selected.

What i want it to return, is a value of the selected node. Lets say its a menu title on the property i want. So instead of the above output, i want "Frontpage, Contact, About Us" etc.

How would that look?

```
var mynode = Page.Cache.GetById(id);
mynode.GetPropertyString("pages")
```

Comment: What is the type of your `mynode` variable?  Is it an instance of `IPublishedContent`?

Comment: @RobPurcell Yes sir :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to install the [Umbraco Core Property Value Converters](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-core-property-value-converters/) nuget package.  This would then provide you with an extension method that you can use to retrieve  a list of nodes in one go.  Then you could use LINQ to select the `menuTitle` property of each page.

```
var menuTitles = mynode.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("pages")
    .Select(x => x.GetPropertyValue<string>("menuTitle"));
```

If you need to you can then use `string.Join()` to combine the menu titles to get a comma-separated list.

Here's a list of using statements that you might need to add:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Our.Umbraco.PropertyConverters;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
```